# How to set focus on a textbox in a new page, opened using fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, focus, fancybox-2

i have 2 pages, page1 and page2. the page2 will be loaded in a fancybox upon click on a link in page1. i want to set the focus to a specific textbox on page2 after it has been loaded. may i know how to do that?

here is the code that i used but doesn't work

```
$('.fancyboxTopic').fancybox({
   helpers:{overlay: {closeClick:false}},
   'padding': 5,
   'width': '840px',
   'height': '95%',
   'autoScale': false,
   'autoHeight': false,
   'autoSize': false,
   'afterClose': function(){window.location.reload(true);},
   'onComplete': function(){$('#topicTitle').focus();}
})
```

and in my link:

```
<a href="page2.asp" class="fancyboxTopic fancybox.iframe">page 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
afterShow: function(){
    $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find("#topicTitle").focus();
}
```

...assuming that all pages are within the same domain.

**NOTE**: you may need to add a `tabindex` attribute to make it work with Chrome :

```
afterShow: function(){
    $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find("#topicTitle").attr("tabindex",1).focus();
}
```

BTW, `onComplete` is an option for fancybox v1.3.x and incompatible with v2.x

Comment: thank you so much @JFK, but that didn't work. Actually, I tried replacing $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find("#topicTitle").attr("tabindex",1).focus() by alert('test'); and it even the alert didn't work.

Comment: BTW, i am using fancybox v2.1.4

Comment: @lordrebs if the alert doesn't work, I think you may be getting a js error somewhere

Comment: you are a life saver! Thank you for the big help. Now it's working very well.